# How to access the new toggleHighlight method?

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul, xbl

We can use `gFindBar.toggleHighlight(true)` before to highlight found result in JS.
After firefox 25 beta, findbar structure changed. This method is still belongs to `gFindBar`, however, through XBL binding.

The method is now defined in `"omni.ja\chrome\toolkit\content\global\bindings\findbar.xml"` or `chrome://global/content/bindings/findbar.xml#findbar`.

Then it's no longer listed in accessible javascript object list. How can I use it in chrome environment? Is there anyway to highlight found result with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't matter that it's not listed (as a method of the XULElement, since it is not), you can continue using it as you did until now.